# Recreating Iconic Electric Zaps

Tags: sound-design, electricity, magical

I am working on some electricity zaps for a spell and have always wondered how these iconic zap sounds were made. I own some quality newer electricity libraries, but none of them have this zap sound that we've come to know. I pitched the audio down two octaves and noticed there is a synthetic like tone that is part of the makeup of the sound effect.

What do you think it could it be? I have tried synths but so far no luck.

[Zap Audio](https://soundcloud.com/oddballaudio/zapstudy/s-dPgJH)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the zap using vital synth and some effects.

here is a demo

I looked at preset share for an electricity preset and found this https://presetshare.com/preset/view?id=818

Then I added several transient shapers, a distortion filter and a frequency shifter (it just changes the pitch), a ring modulator and a vox (morphing formant) filter and I added the frequency of the frequency shifter and one value of the vox to the x y controller as you can see in the demonstration.

What you hear at the end of each zap is the pitch going so high that you cannot hear it anymore (silence). This with the pitch shifting is I think also the way the zap achieved in the sound cloud sample that you provided.